# Cannot execute docker inspect inside Jenkins job

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline, docker-command

I need to execute `docker inspect` from a Jenkins pipeline to get the health status of a container. I tried the following in my pipeline script:

```
def containerHealth = sh(
    script: "docker inspect --format='{{json .State.Health.Status}}' db",
    returnStdout: true
).trim()
```

In my docker-compose file I mounted docker.sock as the following:

```
jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins-master
    ports:
        - '8080:8080'
        - '50000:50000'
    image: jenkins-master
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

However it doesn't work and I get this output message:
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?` But I can execute `docker --version` from the pipeline properly.

Does anyone have an idea how can I get through this?

Comment: Can you place both `docker inspect` and `docker --version` next to each other in a small pipeline and check if only the inspect fails. Please add the log to the question for more info.

Comment: When I place ```docker --version``` and ```docker inspect``` next to each other the console output is ```Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?```

I think it is because I cannot execute docker commands like docker inspect or docker ps from a slave container, I do not know.

Comment: This means you are not able to run even docker —version but you mentioned that you could in your question. What I understand from your setup is, you are running the Jenkins as a docker container and would like to spin a docker from the Jenkins pipeline as well. Am I right?

Comment: Yes I am running jenkins as a container. I use 2 other salve containers in where pipeline code is executed. I am able to run ```docker --version```, but ```docker ps``` or ```docker inspect``` don't work. I would like these commands to work inside my slave containres. Sorry if I was not clear

Comment: Could you add logs ? Please place ‘docker —version’ first and ‘docker inspect’ as a second line in the same pipeline. I would like to understand if the first command is executed as a shell command or a dsl command from docker plug-in in the Jenkins.

Comment: The logs is the following: (sorry it is not very readable in the comment section)
```[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test: docker version)
[Pipeline] sh 
+ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect '--format={{json .State.Health.Status}}' sq1

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?```